# Include image in html using R markdown

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, rstudio

I have an image named icon.png that I want to put in the title of an html created through RStudio. I got it using this script:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $head = $('#header');
     $head.prepend('<img src=\"Icon.png\" style=\"float: left;width: 150px;\"/>')
   });
</script>
```

My question is related with the path of the image, I just got it putting the file in the same folder than the .Rmd...but I'd like to load the image from a folder called assets in the same folder than thr -Rmd

- EDA
  -- assets
- Icon.png
- file.Rmd

Thank you in advanced for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

You change the `img src` Tag in your html script.

like below

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $head = $('#header');
     $head.prepend('<img src=\"assets/Icon.png\" style=\"float: left;width: 150px;\"/>')
   });
</script>
```

Note That with HTML you can't reference image files outside the domain root (web root) see here https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/48448

**Option 2:**

You use Markdown syntax, Note here you can reference image files outside the .rmd file folder

```
---
title: my_document_title ![](../asset_out/Icon.png){width=1in} 
output: html_document
date: "2023-05-09"
---
```

Comment: Thank you @Wael! I think when I tried this I put the slash the other way around: ```assets\Icon.png```. I have another question related, how could I include the same image if this one is a folder out of the EDA folder. I mean: One folder called assets at the same level of folder called EDA. In EDA I'd have the .Rmd file and in assets the logo. How could I do this reference to another folder?

- Assets

-- Icon

- EDA

--EDA.Rmd

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not working when I am looking for a a resource in another folder one level up. Any other idea?

Comment: I edited my answer. I think option 2 with Markdown syntax could be more adapted in your case.